# Use reflection to look for controls in side a composite wpf control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reflection

I trying to write a method that will look at a wpf usercontrol that contains other wpf usercontrol elements.  For example one of the usercontrols contains a datagrid with columns added using xaml.  I want to be able to manipulate a named column in the datagrid. I'm trying to use reflection and I can't find a way to get the internal controls.  I've tried the different get methods (GetProeprties, GetMembers, GetFields) but can't find a collection of internal usercontrols.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx)?

```
var col = uc.FindName("MyColumn") as DataGridColumn;
```

**Edit:** This works in simple cases but for nested UserControls it may not. This being the case you could employ it recursively, here's some sketchy implementation:

```
public static object FindNamedObject(FrameworkElement container, string name)
{
    var target = container.FindName(name);
    if (target == null)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(container);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, i) as FrameworkElement;
            if (child != null)
            {
                target = FindNamedObject(child, name);
                if (target != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, to busy using reflection to take a step back...Thanks

Comment: @Chris: Glad that helped, i just added an additional note as i expected a simple call like this to fail in your case which sounded more complex.